# WebDeploy fails with SSL/TLS error after Visual Studio 2017 15.9 upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy

I use the built-in Web Publishing in Visual Studio 2017 with Web Deploy to deploy to internal websites.  After the 15.9.3 upgrade, web deploy publishing now fails with the error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://[redacted]:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=[redacted]'. 
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This DOES work with the exact same `.sln` file in Visual Studio 2015, so there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the server setup.  The target server is Windows Server 2008 R2.  There have been no other updates, etc.

So, what gives?  How can I re-enable web deploy

Comment: `Windows Server 2008 R2` is probably the problem. Two years ago everyone and their cat's IoT colar abandoned SSL v3 and TLS1.0 with hosters, services, banks, airlines etc *demanding* TLS1.2. Win 2K8R2 requires patching to support TLS1.2 though. The operating systems themselves disabled older protocols.

Comment: Probably the last, most important deadline was [June 30th](https://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/are-you-ready-for-30-june-2018-sayin-goodbye-to-ssl-early-tls), when PCI demanded that everyone stopped using the older protocols. While that doesn't apply to *internal* networks, deviations have to be justified in writing and *NO* IT Pro wants to do that.

Comment: I verified that KB3140245 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi) is already installed, and that the registry entries are set - both under HKLM\...\WinHTTP and under HKLM\...\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL.  Restart & still not working.  Theoretically that would enable TLS 1.2 & set it be a default secure

Comment: NEVERMIND.  I was applying things to sever XYZ-01, and was testing against XYZ-02.  Yay works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MsDeploy fails for webdeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894671/msdeploy-fails-for-webdeploy)

Comment: Make sure you explicitly use `http://` unless you've enabled https for deployment too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The possible dupe was both a different problem (service not responding vs. SSL/TLS) and a different ultimate resolution.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53352947/web-deploy-to-azure-fails-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @PanagiotisKanavos, the problem was enabling TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.2 for Windows Server 2008 R2.  It appears the built-in Web Deploy as part of Visual Studio 2017 15.9.x upgrade no longer supported the now-outdated SSL 2.0.

In the end I followed the instructions for [KB3140245](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi), which included both an update and [setting registry values](https://superuser.com/questions/1080317/how-to-set-tls-protocols-as-default-after-applying-kb3140245) (also immediately below, copied from that answer).

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp

On x64-based computers, DefaultSecureProtocols must also be added to the Wow6432Node path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
```

I also applied these registry keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
```

I probably went heavy-handed, so the above entries may not be required.